# как использовать словарь в словаре и вставить его в оболочку tkinter , а затем высчитать процент цвета

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
colors = {'1' : {'Желтый': 3.1, 'Красный': 91.7, 'Черный': 5.2},
          '2' : {'Желтый': 12.5, 'Черный': 87.5},
          '3' : {'Синий': 50.0, 'Черный': 50.0},
          '4' : {'Белый': 16.0, 'Голубой': 34.0, 'Красный': 50.0}}
n = input("Какой номер цвета? :")
print()
print('Номер цвета:', n, 'C,U')
new_color = {}

for key in colors[n]:
    print(key + ':', colors[n][key], '%')
print()
for s in colors.values():
   new_color.update(colors[n])

x = float(input("Количество грамм краски?:"))
def procent(**new_color):
    for key in new_color:
        print(key, "->", round(x * (new_color[key] / 100), 2)) # находим процент от числа
procent(**new_color)
```

Есть такой интерфейс, как можно привязать словарь и функцию 'round' к программе?

[image]

Comment: Точно так же как и в исходной программе - пользователь вводит значение, по этому значению выбирается значение из словаря. round - аналогично тому как в исходной программе, выполняются вычисления, округляются, потом выводятся. Пока не вижу в чем тут сложности.

Comment: "как использовать словарь в словаре и вставить его в оболочку tkinter..." - начните с "оболочки", а потом уже добавляйте вычисления.

Comment: а пример можно какой-нибудь для наглядности? спасибо

Comment: Ну в смысле, мне за вас реализацию графического интерфейса для вашей задачи написать "для наглядности"?

Comment: Нет пример вставки словаря при вводе в поле Entry

Comment: В обработчике нажатия на какую-то кнопку пишите `n = entry.get()` (вместо input), потом примерно как у вас в программе.

Comment: n = Entry1.get()

new_colors ={}
for key in colors[n]:  пишет key Error почему так?

Comment: Ну видимо ввели что-то, чего не было в словаре. Либо пытаетесь получить текст до того как в текстовое поле что-то ввели.